If certain columns are empty within a range, delete entire row (Excel macro)
I've been trying to work through this problem with VBA macros, but I'm struggling.
My data set looks like this:
    A    B    C    D    E    F    G    H
21  X
22       X
23            X
24       X    X
25                 X    X
26  X    X    X    X

I want a macro which, given a range, will check certain columns for blank cells, and delete the entire row.
For example, in the data set above...

Range A21:H26
Check specified columns (let's say A, B and C)
If any of them are empty, delete the entire row

This should mean only row 26 wouldn't be deleted as it contains values in all of the specified columns.
My attempts
I had tried code like this, but it seems to delete rows with no real rhyme or reason that I can fathom:
Sub DeleteEmptyRowsInRange()
  
    myarray = Range("A21:H30")
  
    For r = 1 To UBound(myarray)
    
        For c = 1 To UBound(myarray, 2)
    
            If c = 4 Or c = 6 Or c = 13 Then
                If Trim(Cells(r + 1, c)) = "" Then rows(r).EntireRow.Delete
            End If
    
        Next c
    
    Next r
  
End Sub

Thanks in advance

Should be doable with a loop and WorksheetFunction.CountBlank or WorksheetFunction.CountA, depending on your logic. Can you share your attempt?

I've tried a few different approaches @BigBen but Excel crashed and I've lost the most recent attempt. I've added one I tried using the UBound function

Golden rule when deleting is to loop backwards to avoid skipping rows.

Platinum rule is to use Union and delete after looping :-)

:) @BigBen - not sure I'd rank it above a golden rule, but I'm no expert.

After deleting rows, the cell range shifts upward. Therefore, the recommended approach is to either delete rows in reverse order or collect all unwanted ranges using the Union function.
Sub DeleteEmptyRowsInRange()
    Dim myArray, r As Long, c, delRng As Range
    myArray = Range("A21:H26").Value
    For r = 1 To UBound(myArray)
        For Each c In Array(1, 2, 3) ' Col A, B, C
            If Len(myArray(r, c)) = 0 Then
                If delRng Is Nothing Then
                    Set delRng = Cells(20 + r, 1)
                Else
                    Set delRng = Application.Union(delRng, Cells(20 + r, 1))
                End If
            End If
        Next c
    Next r
    If Not delRng Is Nothing Then
        delRng.EntireRow.Delete
    End If
End Sub


Delete Rows With Empty Columns

Sub DeleteRowsWithEmptyColumns()
    
    ' Define constants.
    Const RANGE_ADDRESS As String = "A21:M30"
    Dim EMPTY_COLUMNS() As Variant: EMPTY_COLUMNS = VBA.Array(4, 6, 13)

    ' Reference the objects and return the values from the range in an array.
    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = ActiveSheet ' improve!
    Dim rg As Range: Set rg = ws.Range(RANGE_ADDRESS)
    Dim Data() As Variant: Data = rg.Value
    
    ' Validate the numbers in the Empty-columns array.
    If Application.Max(EMPTY_COLUMNS) < 1 Then
        MsgBox """EMPTY-COLUMNS"" contains a number less than 1!", vbExclamation
        Exit Sub
    End If
    If Application.Max(EMPTY_COLUMNS) > UBound(Data, 2) Then
        MsgBox """EMPTY-COLUMNS"" contains a too large number!", vbExclamation
        Exit Sub
    End If
     
    ' Declare additional variables.
    Dim urg As Range, r As Long, c As Long, WasEmptyColumnFound As Boolean
    
    ' Loop through the rows of the array and check if any columns is empty.
    ' If it is, combine the whole row range into a unioned range.
    For r = 1 To UBound(Data, 1)
        For c = 0 To UBound(EMPTY_COLUMNS)
            If IsEmpty(Data(r, EMPTY_COLUMNS(c))) Then ' is empty
            'If Len(CStr(Data(r, EMPTY_COLUMNS(c)))) = 0 Then ' is blank
                If WasEmptyColumnFound Then
                    Set urg = Union(urg, rg.Rows(r))
                Else
                    Set urg = rg.Rows(r)
                    WasEmptyColumnFound = True
                End If
                Exit For ' next row
            End If
        Next c
    Next r
    
    ' Delete rows with empty columns.
    If WasEmptyColumnFound Then urg.Delete Shift:=xlShiftUp
    
    ' Inform.
    If WasEmptyColumnFound Then
        MsgBox "Rows with empty columns deleted.", vbInformation
    Else
        MsgBox "No rows with empty columns found!", vbExclamation
    End If
    
End Sub


Thanks for your answer and your effort, but I had already used and accepted the other answer. +1 though
